# how to escape "/" from mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my .htaccess file thnx to @Gyrocode-com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ fun.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ user.php?u=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/([1-9]+)$ user.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]    #my problem is here

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([1-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?c=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /jokes/$1/ [R]
```

everything works great except whene i try to go to this link

```
localhost/u/user1/2
```

which suppose to take me to page number 2 of `user1`

but instead it catches `user1/2` as the value of variable (u)

and what I want is `u=user1 ; p= 2;`

Comment: Your immediately preceding `^u/(.*)$` is catching **ALL** urls that start with `u/`, so the `user.php?c=$1&p=$2` will never trigger. move the c=$1&p=$2 ruleset ABOVE the ^u/(.*)$ rule

Comment: @MarcB i tried this RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ user.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L] didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your rules can be refactored to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)/?$ fun.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/([1-9]+)$ user.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([1-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?c=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /jokes/$1/ [R,L]
```

1. Using `([^/]+)` instead of `(.*)` to restrict matching to anything before `/`
2. Instead of using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` before each rule it is better to use that in a separate rule as shown.